# How to pass multiple value in a single in retrofit request

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am using Retrofit2 and RxJava in my application. I have to pass multiple values corresponding to single key. Below is my request URL

```
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=28.46&lon=77.03&exclude=hourly,alerts,minutely&appid=01s
```

Now in above URL there is **exclude** key in which multiple parameters are passing how to add these in my interface. Below is my interface.

**ApiService.class**

```
interface ApiService {

@GET("data/2.5/onecall")
fun getCurrenttemp(@Query("lat") lat:String,
                   @Query("lon") lon:String,
                   @Query("exclude") exclude:String,
                   @Query("appid") appid:String):Observable<Climate>

}
```

How can I make the desired request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `exclude` parameter portion in the [documentation](https://openweathermap.org/api/one-call-api) of One Call API says,

> By using this parameter you can exclude some parts of the weather data from the API response. It should be a comma-delimited list (without spaces).

So it's not asking for multiple values, it's rather one String value with comma-separated option tags with no spaces between them. Just put "`hourly,alerts,minutely`" in a String variable & pass that string as you already have in the following line of code, `@Query("exclude") exclude:String`, via your interface and it should work:

```
var excludeParamToPass = "hourly,alerts,minutely"
```

One example of API from that same [reference](https://openweathermap.org/api/one-call-api):

```
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=33.441792&lon=-94.037689&exclude=hourly,daily&appid={API key}
```